# Minimum volume covering ellipse

Tags: geometry, optimization, conic-sections, quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization

Given a convex polygon in the plane, consider the smallest-area ellipse that contains this polygon. This is the "minimal volume covering ellipsoid" or "minimal volume enclosing ellipsoid" (MVEE), and apparently it's been studied quite a bit. Is there a bound on the volume of this MVEE? In other words, what is the following?

$$\mbox{sup}\{\mbox{Vol}(E):E\mbox{ is an MVEE for some convex }K\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}\mbox{ satisfying Vol}(K)=1\}$$

More generally, of course, I wonder what this value would be in any dimension. I'm interested in convex polygons and convex bodies. For general polygons the answer is no, as shown below.

Comment: I guess you talk about convex polygon. Isn't it?

Comment: Indeed. I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to look into the theory of Löwner-John ellipsoids (which states that the relation between the (by volume) largest possible inscribed ellipsoid inside a convex set $K$, and an outer circumscribing ellispoid, is bounded by $n$ ($\sqrt{n}$ for symmetric bodies). From there, you would get a volume bound.)

Comment: I've found that for any convex $K$ and its MVEE $E$, one has (up to translations) $\frac{1}{n}E \subset K \subset E$. It follows that if $\textrm{Vol}(K)=1$ then $\textrm{Vol}(E)\leq n^{n}$. But is this the lowest bound for $\textrm{Vol}(E)$ given $\textrm{Vol}(K)=1$? It seems like quite a large number...

Answer (score 2):

No. Take a cross-shaped polygon and make the branches as thin as you like. For a unit area, the bounding circle can be arbitrarily large.

[image]